# Why is this valid javascript? What are those parenthesis doing? (not an anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

```
(this.template = this.name
            ? new UrlBuilder(name, absolute, this.ziggy).construct()
            : ''),
            (this.urlParams = this.normalizeParams(params));
```

I'm very confused about what the comma is doing there, source found [here](https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy/blob/master/src/js/route.js#L11)

Comment: If you have a better title for the question, please help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: The comma operator here does not make any sense (except creating confusion), because the result of the expression is not assigned anywhere. So in the given case, it would be equal to `this.template = this.name ? new UrlBuilder(name, absolute, this.ziggy).construct() : ''; this.urlParams = this.normalizeParams(params);`. And even if the result would be assigned to something, it still would in most cases be more a sign of a bad coding style than anything useful.